# changing the orientation of a video loading in iframe

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I load a youtube video in an iframe in my ios app, the code for which is below:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = %@\"/></head> <body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"> <div><object width=\"%@\" height=\"%@\">  <param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param> <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>    <embed src=\"%@\"   type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%@\" height=\"%@\"></embed>    </object></div></body></html>",@"320",@"320",@"460",self.videoURL,self.videoURL,@"320",@"460"];
```

Now, when the frame is of dimensions 320x460, it works fine. But on changing the orientation, I need the iframe to resize to 480x300. But that will be possible if I load the html string in my webview again after changing dimensions, which will cause the video to start loading again, which is not I want. I want the video to resume from the point upto which it has been played back. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

// Most important use video tag in html to play that video then and then only following trick works or you can achieve same by using some youtube api for IOS

when you change orientation of device call Javascript method which pause current video and call method which returns current playback time of video store that time in variable. when change in orientation completes load html string with width and height attribute set for video tag according to your requirement and call javascript code which starts playing that video from the last playback time which you have stored in variable.

// Take help of w3schools website for javascript code and HTML related stuff. and search for how to call javascript from objective c and vice-verse and also search for youtube apis for controlling video from webview of IOS.

you will defiantly  get solution. i have done similar thing in one of my project successfully.

All the best.